<Svelte> making image-map in mobile
I'm trying to make image-mapping in svelte. This is working in PC but not in mobile.
I want to import rwdImageMaps and this is controlled by jQuery.
Because of this, I installed jQuery, also I succeed in printing console.log("hello") in jquery space.
And then I also pasted cdn of rwdImageMaps.
But whenever I put jQuery('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps(); it never works.
-app.html
<head>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <!-- Include jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/1.6/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-eZB7hQa0bRlrKMQ2njpP0d/Klu6o30Gsr8e5FUCjUT3fSlnVkm/1J14n58BuwgaMuObrGb7SvUfQuF8qFsPU4g=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body class="layout-light top-menu">
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-W43TQVRR" height="0" width="0"
            style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <div>%sveltekit.body%</div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
        });
    </script>
</body>

-component
<script>
    import panzoom from 'panzoom';
    import Modal from './Modal.svelte';
    import Toolbar from './Toolbar.svelte';
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import 'image-map-resizer';

    onMount(() => {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            console.log('hello') //<---- this works
            jQuery('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
        });
    });
</script>

+add (body)
<script>
    import panzoom from 'panzoom';
    import Modal from './Modal.svelte';
    import Toolbar from './Toolbar.svelte';
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let instance;
    let showModal = false;
    let modalTitle = '';
    let modalContent1 = '';
    let modalContent2 = '';
    let modalContent3 = '';
    let modalContent4 = '';
    let modalPicture = '';
    let modlaTitleCircle = '';
    let modalTel = '';
    let modalFacebook = '';
    let modalInsta = '';
    let modalHomepage = '';

    function initPanzoom(node) {
        instance = panzoom(node, {
            bounds: true,
            boundsPadding: 0.1,
            maxZoom: 3.5,
            minZoom: 1,
            contain: 'inside'
        });
    }

    function openModal(
        title,
        content1,
        content2,
        content3,
        content4,
        imageUrl,
        circle,
        tel,
        facebook,
        insta,
        homepage
    ) {
        modalTitle = title;
        modalContent1 = content1;
        modalContent2 = content2;
        modalContent3 = content3;
        modalContent4 = content4;
        showModal = true;
        modalPicture = imageUrl;
        modlaTitleCircle = circle;
        modalTel = tel;
        modalFacebook = facebook;
        modalInsta = insta;
        modalHomepage = homepage;
    }

    function closeModal() {
        showModal = false;
    }
    onMount(() => {
        jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
            jQuery('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
        });

        console.log('hello');
    });
</script>
<style>
    .btn_third{
        background-color:#f8f5e2 ;
        border:.0625rem solid #eee;
        color:#517947;
        border-radius: .625rem;
    }
    .btn_third a:hover{
        color:#333;
    }
    .btn svg{
        width:1.5625rem; height:1.5625rem;
    }
</style>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <Toolbar {instance} />
    <div class="btn btn_third">
        <a href="https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5266/download" download="중랑문화재단_손길지도.pdf"
            >손길 지도 다운로드 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="currentColor" d="M5 20h14v-2H5m14-9h-4V3H9v6H5l7 7z"/></svg></a>
        </div>
        
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;  margin-top:2em;">
    <div use:initPanzoom style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
        
        <img
            src="https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5238/download"
            style="width: 100%; height: auto;"
            usemap="#store"
        />
    </div>
    <map name="store">
        <area
            alt="한땀바느질공방"
            title="한땀바느질공방"
            href="#store1"
            coords="813,469,926,489"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '한땀바느질공방',
                    '손으로 예술을 짓고',
                    '나를 이야기하는 곳',
                    '#퀼트 #자수 #인형 #방과후·동아리 수업',
                    '중랑구 봉화산로194 신아타운 3층 312호',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5222/download',
                    'rgba(233, 109, 170, 0.9)'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="후조방"
            title="후조방"
            href="#store2"
            coords="810,494,898,517"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '후조방',
                    '변신이 기대되는 곳',
                    '',
                    '#목공예',
                    '중랑구 봉화산로 194 신아타운 3층 365호',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5224/download',
                    'rgba(155, 100, 45, 0.9)'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="비취연"
            title="비취연"
            href="#store3"
            coords="500,502,588,593"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '비취연',
                    '나전칠기,',
                    '천년의 역사를 잇는 문화유산',
                    '#나전칠기',
                    '중랑구 동일로 148나길 10-14',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5219/download',
                    'rgba(48, 180, 46, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1306-5739',
                    'https://www.facebook.com/yullhyeon2704'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="도자공방 재이뜰"
            title="도자공방 재이뜰"
            href="#store4"
            coords="381,575,458,652"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '도자공방 재이뜰',
                    '재이뜰에서 기분이 좋아지는',
                    '흙 놀이를 해보세요',
                    '#도자 작업실 #도자기 화분 #도자기 그릇',
                    '중랑구 동일로 149길 64 2층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5226/download',
                    'rgba(235, 224, 70, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1348-0681',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/gogocera_clay'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="라탄배미공방"
            title="라탄배미공방"
            href="#store5"
            coords="512,610,588,703"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '라탄배미공방',
                    `나에게 '나'를 선물하는 시간,`,
                    '사계절 누리는 라탄',
                    '#라탄 공예',
                    '중랑구 동일로140길 7-4 1층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5217/download',
                    'rgba(48, 180, 46, 0.9)',
                    '010-5495-3421',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/baemi_gongbang'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="나무소리"
            title="나무소리"
            href="#store6"
            coords="591,635,668,726"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '나무소리',
                    '나무 향기 가득한',
                    `따뜻한 공간`,
                    '#목공예 #목공예품 #나무도마',
                    '서울 중랑구 봉화산로 97 2층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5230/download',
                    'rgba(155, 100, 45, 0.9)',
                    '010-5141-3203',
                    '',
                    'namusori_studio'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="아틀리에 랑"
            title="아틀리에 랑"
            href="#store7"
            coords="699,678,790,772"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '아틀리에 랑',
                    '나무 향기 가득한',
                    `따뜻한 공간`,
                    '#목공예 #목공예품 #나무도마',
                    '중랑구 망우로55길 11-10',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5237/download',
                    'rgba(48, 180, 46, 0.9)',
                    '010-7610-3131',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/manbok_knit_crochet',
                    'm.smartstore.naver.com/manbok_knit_crochet'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="얼렁뚱땅작업소"
            title="얼렁뚱땅작업소"
            href="#store8"
            coords="793,604,872,709"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '얼렁뚱땅작업소',
                    '평범한 뜨개는 거부한다!',
                    `특별한 염색 실로 만든 나만의 스웨터 `,
                    '#손뜨개 #실 염색',
                    '중랑구 망우로55길 11-10',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5221/download',
                    'rgba(233, 109, 170, 0.9)',
                    '02-432-6738',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/artcraft_rang',
                    'https://cafe.naver.com/atelierrang'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="THISISMINE"
            title="THISISMINE"
            href="#store9"
            coords="836,709,926,794"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    'THISISMINE',
                    '세상 어디에도 없는',
                    '소중한 내 것을 만드는 목공방',
                    '#목공예 #맞춤 제작',
                    '중랑구 신내로 8 2층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5234/download',
                    'rgba(155, 100, 45, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1335-9355',
                    '',
                    '',
                    ''
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="비단가죽공방"
            title="비단가죽공방"
            href="#store10"
            coords="986,627,1077,729"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '비단 가죽공방',
                    '지친 일상을 힐링해 주는',
                    '따뜻한 가죽 공방',
                    '#가죽 공예 #미싱 없이 손으로',
                    '서울 중랑구 양원역로 9 1층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5236/download',
                    'rgba(229, 124, 66, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1379-8965',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/v.i.d.a.n_',
                    'https://blog.naver.com/3698rla'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="스위티공방"
            title="스위티공방"
            href="#store11"
            coords="1003,752,1094,840"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '스위티 공방',
                    '세상에 하나밖에 없는',
                    '감성 디자인',
                    '#핸드 퀼트 #머신 퀼트 #주흐모던 자수 #퀼트 인형',
                    '중랑구 망우로 466 2층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5233/download',
                    'rgba(233, 109, 170, 0.9)',
                    '02-6452-2272',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/sweetiequilt_jusaem',
                    'https://www.sweetiequilt.com/'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="배꽃공방"
            title="배꽃공방"
            href="#store12"
            coords="887,840,969,945"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '배꽃공방',
                    '꼼지락꼼지락',
                    '손으로 만드는 예쁜 세상 ',
                    '#천연 제품 #비누 공예 #토탈 공예 #원예',
                    '중랑구 봉우재로 213-26',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5216/download',
                    'rgba(154, 139, 205, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1345-8140',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/kity8890',
                    'https://blog.naver.com/poh89'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="다정한손뜨개"
            title="다정한손뜨개"
            href="#store13"
            coords="779,806,870,885"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '다정한 손뜨개',
                    '마음 담아 한 코,',
                    '다정한 손뜨개',
                    '#손뜨개 #코바늘·대바늘 #초보자 기초반',
                    '중랑구 망우로60길 37 402호',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5220/download',
                    'rgba(233, 109, 170, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1345-8140',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/dajeong_knit',
                    ''
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="바이핸드"
            title="바이핸드"
            href="#store14"
            coords="421,800,500,882"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '바이핸드',
                    '향기로 행복을 만드는 공방',
                    '',
                    '#향기 공방 #아로마테라피 #조향 비누 화장품 체험 #자격증반',
                    '중랑구 중랑천로 30길 60 1층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5218/download',
                    'rgba(154, 139, 205, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1322-7856',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/beatrix_nature',
                    'https://blog.naver.com/nature-green'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="송리사이클링"
            title="송리사이클링"
            href="#store15"
            coords="338,777,415,877"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '송리사이클링',
                    '업사이클 유리로',
                    '일상이 반짝반짝 ',
                    '#유리 공예',
                    '중랑구 중랑천로 20길 35 지하1층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5231/download',
                    'rgba(48, 180, 46, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1317-9442',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/moj9442song',
                    ''
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="스튜디오흐린비누작업실"
            title="스튜디오흐린비누작업실"
            href="#store16"
            coords="526,953,617,1073"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '스튜디오흐린비누작업실',
                    '비누로 그린 그림',
                    '',
                    '#비누 공예 #캔들 공예',
                    '중랑구 겸재로 15길 21 1층 3호',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5232/download',
                    'rgba(154, 139, 205, 0.9)',
                    '02-6403-0221',
                    '',
                    '',
                    ''
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="레아솝"
            title="레아솝"
            href="#store17"
            coords="531,1098,608,1184"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '레아솝',
                    '비누를 만드는',
                    '힐링의 시간',
                    '#비누 공예',
                    '중랑구 동일로 92길 35 킴스빌 B동 1층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5228/download',
                    'rgba(154, 139, 205, 0.9)',
                    '010-8280-1796',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/leha_playground',
                    'https://blog.naver.com/leha_playground'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="아뜰리에소설"
            title="아뜰리에소설"
            href="#store18"
            coords="494,1249,571,1337"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '아뜰리에소설',
                    '내가 행복해지는 소설,',
                    '향초공방 ',
                    '#캔들 공예',
                    '중랑구 사가정로 46나길 3 1층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5215/download',
                    'rgba(154, 139, 205, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1313-2194',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/atelier.sosul',
                    'https://blog.naver.com/ateliersosul'
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="제이로시뜨개공방"
            title="제이로시뜨개공방"
            href="#store19"
            coords="580,1206,671,1297"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '제이로시뜨개공방',
                    '엄마의 마음으로',
                    '한 코, 두 코',
                    '#손뜨개',
                    '중랑구 사가정로52길 9 2층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5227/download',
                    'rgba(233, 109, 170, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1313-2194',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/jrossi_knitting',
                    ''
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="오늘의나에게"
            title="오늘의나에게"
            href="#store20"
            coords="708,1138,784,1229"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '오늘의나에게',
                    '토닥토닥, 지친 일상 속에',
                    '오롯이 나에게 집중하며 힐링하는 캘리 공방',
                    '#캘리그라피 #민화',
                    '중랑구 면목로 44길 79 3층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5235/download',
                    'rgba(48, 180, 46, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1398-1397',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/bandicalli',
                    ''
                );
            }}
        />
        <area
            alt="메이크띵즈"
            title="메이크띵즈"
            href="#store21"
            coords="520,1394,617,1474"
            shape="rect"
            on:click={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                openModal(
                    '메이크띵즈',
                    '“만들어 쓰는 즐거움”',
                    '도자기 작업실 메이크띵즈 ',
                    '#도자기 공예',
                    '중랑구 면목로 27길 49 1층',
                    'https://www.jnfac.or.kr/api/files/5229/download',
                    'rgba(235, 224, 70, 0.9)',
                    '0507-1365-6929',
                    '',
                    'https://www.instagram.com/make_things_studio',
                    'https://blog.naver.com/ceramiae'
                );
            }}
        />
    </map>
</div>

{#if showModal}
    <Modal
        title={modalTitle}
        imageUrl={modalPicture}
        circle={modlaTitleCircle}
        content1={modalContent1}
        content2={modalContent2}
        content3={modalContent3}
        content4={modalContent4}
        tel={modalTel}
        facebook={modalFacebook}
        insta={modalInsta}
        homepage={modalHomepage}
        on:close={closeModal}
    />
{/if}



I added body. Thank you for helping me!
